# Edit permission for ssh key users in Virtual Studio Team Service

Tags: azure-devops, ssh-keys, user-permissions

I added my user the ssh based authentication but i don't know how to set the permission for that user. Anybody know?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for the users who use ssh protocol is accordance with what the permissions set for the user in VSTS web page. And you can use below aspects to set permissions for the user:

- #### Set permission for the user which projects (git repositories in the projects) can be access

  In Users page (https://account.visualstudio.com/_settings/users) -> click `…` button for the user -> Manage projects -> select the project you want the user to access -> save changes.

  [image]

  So the user with ssh protocol can only access to the git repositories in the select project(s).
- #### Set permission for the user for repositories and branches

  In a certain project, set permission for the repo(s) and branch in Repositories Page (https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_settings/repositories) as below:

  Select a certain level (all repositories, a repository or a branch) you want to set permission for the user -> Add the user -> then set detail permissions for the user -> save changes.

  [image]

Such as if I set the permission (deny to force push to `product1` repo's `f` branch in `Git2` project) for a user who use ssh protocol as below:

[image]

When the user try to force push changes to product1's `f` branch, it will be failed:

[image]